# How do I render GeoHashes with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, spatial, postgis

Are there any [geohash](http://www.bigfastblog.com/geohash-intro) implementation for PostgreSQL? I couldn't find any.

Comment: you mean postgis ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostGIS supports it with [`ST_GeoHash`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeoHash.html)

> `ST_GeoHash` — Return a GeoHash representation (geohash.org) of the geometry.